# Dynamically load an image into a dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

How can I dynamically load an image into a dialog box in android

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null));
}
```

I can only link static buttons and images into the view.

If I try to link images dynamically like

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

image is being returned as a null object

Comment: at which place you are getting reference to Image findViewById(R.id.image); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vg.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        builder.setView(vg);
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: it raises an exception requiring requestFeature() to be called

Comment: Oops that was coz i had the oncreateview method overwritten.